# change class of element, on each mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change class of element, everytime I click on it.

on css section I have:

```
myButton.btn_first_look {
    /* some atributes */
}
myButton.btn_second_look{
    /* some atributes */
}
```

little jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn_first_look');
    $(this).toggleClass('btn_second_look');
})};
```

So, when I click on element, I expect jquery script to change element class from `btn_first_look` to `btn_second_look` and otherwise.

But boom. Nothing happend

Comment: Post your html for that button.

Comment: Your function is toggling both classes at the same time.

Comment: You have syntax error, check your console

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toggleClass` will take care of add and remove by itself

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('btn_second_look btn_first_look');
 };
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/ms4sS/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeClass()` and `addClass()` respectively

```
 $('#myButton').click(function() {         
      //if button has class btn_first_look
       if($(this).hasClass('btn_first_look')){
         $(this).removeClass('btn_first_look');
         $(this).addClass('btn_second_look');
       }

       //if button has class btn_second_look
       else if($(this).hasClass('btn_second_look')){
          $(this).removeClass('btn_second_look');
          $(this).addClass('btn_first_look');
       }        
 });
```

This adds whichever class the button doesn't have, and removes the class it does.

Comment: suppose if the button has 'btn_second_look' class from start...will your code work?

Comment: @Arjit please have a look udpated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

If your element has class `btn_first_look`  from the start, you can write

```
$(element).toggleClass("btn_first_look btn_second_look");
```

This will remove class `btn_first_look` and add class `btn_second_look`. If you do that again, it will remove class `btn_second_look` and reinstate class `btn_first_look` .

Answer (score 0):

Add a parenthesis at the very end. Your first `(function()` has no close, so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

That will work for you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myButton').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('btn_first_look btn_second_look');
  });
});
```